# Credentials for Services changed while app was running

Tags: ibm-cloud, message-hub

Is it possible for the VCAP_SERVICES' credentials (api key/username/password) to change while the app is running ? 
I saw that 2 of my services (message hub and sendgrid) that were bound to my node.js app had changed credentials shortly (about 2hrs) after deployment and as a result all my connections to those services failed because, I had stored the credentials into a variable on app start.
Has it happened to anyone else before ? Is that normal ? What is the best approach to handle that scenario ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The credentials in VCAP_SERVICES can change if you unbind the application from message hub, delete and recreate the instance of message hub, or delete and recreate the instance of the application.

Since VCAP_SERVICES is an environment variable, it can't change during the lifetime of a particular application. VCAP_SERVICES should not change even if you restaged the application.  This is because this value is set at the point in time where the application is associated with the service (e.g. when you say "use this service" in the Bluemix API).

Comment: Thanks for the response @Rajini. What you said is true, I redeployed the app when message-hub stopped that caused the credentials to change. But I still see that message-hub stops after 2-4hrs and I have to re-deploy the app to fix it. May be I will start a different thread on this, but any other examples for message-hub other than the Bluemix documentation?

Comment: ...especially where the producer and consumer are on different applications?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of this happening before.  Is it possible someone manually changed something or recreated the services?

Comment: With message-hub the credentials are different every time the node app is redeployed. Is it because the service is unbound and re-bound to the app during deployment? This does not happen with CloudantDB which is also bound to the same app, similarly.

Comment: Is your redeploy using the no-route option?  If not, could that be what is causing the issue - that a different route is being generated with each redeploy?